# php save image from url using curl but validate it first

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

I found the following function searching SO

```
function grab_image($url,$saveto){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

this should work to save an image but how can i check the image `dimensions`, `size` and `filetype` first in order to validate that its valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you fire the curl, you can read the image directly using

```
$url = 'http://exmaple.com/img/some.png';
$imgInfo = getimagesize($url);
print_r($imgInfo);
```

Comment: but how can i get its file size? how kb, mb it is?

Comment: In the curl setup, set CURLOPT_HEADER true so the header will   have the Content-Length:

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$raw = curl_exec($ch);
if ($raw === FALSE) {
   die("Fetch failed");
}

// get size
$size = strlen($raw);

// get dimensions
$img = imagecreatefromstring($raw);
$x = imagesx($img);
$y = imagesy($img);

// get mime type
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$type = $finfo->buffer($raw); // e.g. image/jpeg
```

Comment: cant i process the photo upload procedure the same way as i do when i upload it as a file? or i need to create a new function using the above procedure? - the above strlen($row) wont work since the $row is a resource

Comment: you could use `file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])` to slurp the uploaded file into a variable, then use the string-based validation. Or write your curl-fetched file out to disk, then use disk-based validation.

Comment: but i am not uploading an image.. i am using a URL to get the image and validate it...